# Swift Package Manager Not able to resolve Kitura version above 1.4

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, kitura

I am trying with a sample Swift on server (using Kitura) app and using swift package manager to resolve the dependencies.

Here is my sample `Package.swift` file.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Kitura_Swift_Server",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 4)
    ])
```

My problem is if I change the minor version of Kitura framework to anything above 4, I get the error `error: unsatisfiable`. Although 1.7.1 is the latest Kitura version but `swift build` is not resolving it.

Anyone have any idea why it could behave so?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue before when you've already run `swift build` and the `.build` directory is created, then you change something in your `Package.swift`. That said, I've had no issue using Kitura 1.7.x as my lone dependency.

I recommend you change your Kitura version to 1.7.x and run `swift package update` (in Swift 3.1.1) if you want your dependencies updated.

If that doesn't work, it doesn't hurt to start fresh and delete the `.build` directory, then run `swift build`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried deleting build folder but it didn't help. When I run 'swift package update', my machine hangs.

Comment: I was able to download dependencies and compile using the` Package.swift` you posted. What version of Swift are you using? Also, have you tried deleting the `Package.pins` file and building (if using the latest Swift toolchain)?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i started having this problem with swift 4.2.1 and have tried deleting Package.resolved and .build